# Convert multiple values to integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, integer

I have code like this

```
def some_data():

    file_data = open(r"some.txt","r")

    result = {}
    for line in file_data:
        values = line.split(sep="\t")
        if values[-1][-1:] == "\n":
            values[-1] = values[-1][:-1]
        else:
            values[-1] = values[-1]
        result.update({values[0]: [values[1], values[2],values[3], values[4]]})

    return result
```

That gives me output:

```
{'130121322X': ['90', '50', '40', '60'], '130121323Y': ['80', '70', '60', '60'], '130121325X': ['100', '90', '75', '50'], '130121334Y': ['90', '90', '80', '85'], '130121337Z': ['95', '60', '70', '80'], '130121338X': ['50', '50', '40', '60']}
```

How can I convert the multiple values to integers? So should like this i.e:

```
{'130121322X': [90, 50, 40, 60], '130121323Y': [80, 70, 60, 60], '130121325X': [100, 90, 75, 50], '130121334Y': [90, 90, 80, 85], '130121337Z': [95, 60, 70, 80], '130121338X': [50, 50, 40, 60]}
```

Comment: You can use `map` for converting them to int like this: `map(int, values)`

Answer (score 0):

Now there's a bunch of parentheses, but...

```py
d = {
    '130121322X': ['90', '50', '40', '60'], 
    '130121323Y': ['80', '70', '60','60'], 
    '130121325X': ['100', '90', '75', '50'], 
    '130121334Y': ['90', '90', '80', '85'], 
    '130121337Z': ['95', '60', '70', '80'], 
    '130121338X': ['50', '50', '40', '60']
}

dict(map(lambda x: (x[0],list(map(int,x[1]))),d.items()))
```

Also, it seems like you have a file with columns, separated by '`\t'`. You might use `pandas.read_csv`. It works with .txt files just fine and gives you a `DataFrame`, that lets you operate with your data functionally. Check [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and [the guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html)
Let's say, you have a .txt file like

```
some    2   3   4
random  6   7   8
text    10  11  12
```

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path/to/txt',sep='\t', 
                 names=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
print(df)
```

to get a data frame

```
     col1  col2  col3  col4
0    some     2     3     4
1  random     6     7     8
2    text    10    11    12
```

Also, all the integers are already read as integers